# Trying to run multiple async task in a c# console application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I have a main method that calls methods from another class, these methods are all async Task methods but don't return anything. They are sending get request to a REST API client.
Here's an example of one method in a class called DbRequestHandler:

```
public static async Task ReadRooms(HttpClient client)
{
    // HTTP GET all rooms
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/v1/rooms");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("xmlRooms.xml", false);

        string rooms = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        file.Write(rooms);
        file.Flush();

        Console.Out.Write(rooms);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Here is the Main method that runs the program by calling DbRequestHandler:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CentrisURL"];

    if (url == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to load API url");
    }

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    //DbRequestHandler.ReadRooms(client).Wait();
    //DbRequestHandler.ReadRoomsType(client).Wait();
    //DbRequestHandler.ReadCourses(client).Wait();
    DbRequestHandler.ReadTeachers(client).Wait();
}
```

My problem is that I cant seem to figure out how to call all these separate methods that are all async Task method, I know it has to do with .Wait() but I haven't been able to find the right solution, I have tried a few. If I un-comment all the calls to DbRequestHandler methods the first line is the only one that is executed. Is anyone that has a suggestion for how to solve this? I'm having difficulty understanding async Tasks. Hope my question is clear. I will read any link that you recommend reading but I can't promise I will understand :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    var url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CentrisURL"];

    if (url == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to load API url");
    }

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    await Task.WhenAll(
        new Task[] {
            DbRequestHandler.ReadRooms(client),
            DbRequestHandler.ReadRoomsType(client),
            DbRequestHandler.ReadCourses(client),
            DbRequestHandler.ReadTeachers(client),
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This looks really good and I though this would work, but I get the same error I got with another solution, that's: "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

Comment: @Aron You can't make `Main`  async. If you are writing a console application you have to call `.Wait()`. Your solution would be correct if this was a WCF or winforms project in a event though.

Comment: If it would be allowed what would be the purpose of making Main async? Who would await it? Remove both `await` and `async` and add `Wait()` to the call to `Task.WhenAll()`.

Answer (score 5):

> If I un-comment all the calls to DbRequestHandler methods the first line is the only one that is executed.

That sounds like your actual application is *not* a console app like the one you posted. I see no reason why your original code wouldn't work. I just ran your code and it executed two methods just fine.

If you want to do asynchronous work serially (one after another), then you should use `await`:

```
await DbRequestHandler.ReadRoomsAsync(client);
await DbRequestHandler.ReadRoomsTypeAsync(client);
...
```

If you want to do all the asynchronous work simultaneously, then you should use `await Task.WhenAll`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(DbRequestHandler.ReadRoomsAsync(client),
    DbRequestHandler.ReadRoomsTypeAsync(client), ...);
```

Either way, if you're putting this into a console app, I recommend your `Main` be changed to only call one other method and `Wait` on it, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  MainAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
  var url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CentrisURL"];
  ...
}
```

This helps your code stay clean by keeping the blocking code in `Main` where it belongs, and nowhere else.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with `async-await` and Console Applications, you always end up doing things you wont do in places where you have a custom `SynchronizationContext` (such as Winforms or WPF).

In your example, you can use [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall(v=vs.110).aspx) on all tasks executed in main to simply wait till they all complete:

```
Task readRoomsTask = DbRequestHandler.ReadRooms(client);

Task readRoomTypeTask = DbRequestHandler.ReadRoomsType(client);
Task readCoursesTask = DbRequestHandler.ReadCourses(client);
Task readTeachersTask = DbRequestHandler.ReadTeachers(client);

Task.WaitAll(readRoomsTask, readRoomTypeTask, reachCoursesTask, reqdTeachersTask);
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to solve this would be to create an array of tasks and then wait on all of the to complete

```
if (url == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to load API url");
        }

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
       Task[] taskArray = new Task[4];
       taskArray[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(await DbRequestHandler.ReadRooms(client));
       taskArray[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(DbRequestHandler.ReadRoomsType(client));
       taskArray[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(DbRequestHandler.ReadCourses(client));
       taskArray[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(DbRequestHandler.ReadTeachers(client));
       Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
```

More information about running multiple tasks can be found on msdn [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: -1 Incorrect usage of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. In that it is used. At all.

Comment: The OP's question is on asynchronous programming not threaded programming. Besides..You should NEVER write `Task.Factory.StartNew(await ...)`.

Comment: Neither of these solutions worked because I'm doing this in Main...I found another solution, just made a new method in the DbRequestHandler that has the first solution, with the multible tasks, then I call this function in the main runner class :) ...thanks for the quick responses, help alot!